# Quel est le sens de similitudes de culture à culture？

Tags: sens

[image]

Quel est le sens de 《les similitudes de culture à culture》？

Comment: Il faut préciser ce que tu ne comprends pas, est-ce le mot [similitude](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/similitude), qui se trouve facilement dans un dictionnaire, ou « de culture à culture ». Quand on fait une citation il faut citer sa source.  De culture à culture : d'une culture à l'autre

Answer (score 3):

Cette phrase signifie simplement que si l'on compare les cultures (au sens de sociétés, civilisations) entre elles, on trouvera parfois des choses similaires, et parfois des choses différentes.